# Drop down value selection using C# and Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I am desperately seeking for solution when I am clicking on drop down list to choose another country name, where by default a country 'Canada' is selected.
I tried all possible ways using xpath, CSS selector everywhere successful but here unable.
Please advise

HTML code is:

```
<div id="ctl09_ctl02_ctl00_pay_ddInternationalCountriesCA_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" style="width: 182px;">
    <a class="chzn-single" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <span>Canada</span>
    <div>
        <b></b>
    </div>
</a>
<div class="chzn-drop" style="left: -9000px; z-index: 1; width: 180px; top: 25px;">
    <div class="chzn-search">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="characterFilter(this);" style="width: 166px;">
</div>
```

Comment: Is the drop-downs name `chzn-drop`?  If that is the case, can't you just look-up the control based on `className`?

Comment: Does `chzn` a shortening of `chosen`?  Aka...does that class change if you are hovered over it (or something similar)?  If so, then you will need to use Actions (or whatever the C# alternative is)

Comment: What have you tried? Show us the exact code you are using right now and any errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is the [Chosen jQuery plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), that wraps  plain html `select` elements to provide a richer UX experience.

From a testing /selenium point of view, you are no longer working with the actual `Select` element which is now hidden from view and replaced by the choosen jquery controls.

The option elements from the original select should be listed within the `chzn-drop` div as `li` elements, but I do not see them in your example code.

The following code will help you select from the Chosen jquery select elements. Requires the options to have ids, or you will need to use a different way to select. Share your full HTML for the `<div class='chzn-drop' >` in that case  and I will update.

```
//the chzn div container that wraps the select element  
var chznDivContainer = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl09_ctl02_ctl00_pay_ddInternationalCountriesCA_chzn"));

//the available options in the chzn select
var availableOptions = chznDivContainer.FindElements(By.XPath(".//div[@class='chzn-drop']/ul/li")).ToList();

//search for the item that you want to select, eg: Australia
var optionFound = this.AvailableOptions.FirstOrDefault(el => el.Text.Trim().Equals("Australia"));

//if required option is found, select it using jquery
if (found != null)
{
    var script = string.Format("jQuery('#{0}').mouseup();", found.GetAttribute("id"));
    IJavaScriptExecutor jsExecutor = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
    jsExecutor.ExecuteScript(script);
}
```

Comment: Here is the code <td id="ctl09_ctl02_ctl00_pay_tdInternationalCountriesCA">
<div id="dvInternationalCountriesCA" class="sltinput floatlt posrelative">
 <div class="floatlt">
 <select name="ctl09$ctl02$ctl00$pay$ddInternationalCountriesCA" id="ctl09_ctl02_ctl00_pay_ddInternationalCountriesCA" class="lit payment-input chzn-select" onchange="SetDomesticBillingAddressFormat();ChangeCSSForDropdownList(this);UpdateStateInAdditionalServicesController();ShowInsuranceDeclinePopUp()" style="width:150px;">
<option selected="selected" value="Select">Select</option>
      <option value="CA">Canada</option>

Comment: Can you edit your question and add full contents of the `<div class="chzn-drop" .. >` element? That should have the options also. I have updated my answer but the implementation for your specific item might be different.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a SelectElement. Create one by

```
SelectElement select = new SelectElement(dropdownlist);
```

here is the documentation: [SelectElement](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_SelectElement__ctor.htm)

Comment: also did this..but generate alert comes "Element should have been select but div".